# How to save Child Of relative transform to absolute

Tags: armature, constraints

Hello I have few animations in my character, in one it will be helpful to have child of constraint, but in future, I will need to remove it, so how I can get absolute position and rotation for some frames and apply it to work without this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

In the list of keying sets you will find several "Visual" options, these options keyframe values of the visual location/rotation/scale, which is after constraints have been applied.

[image: keying set menu]

The only explanation for visual keying I can find is in the [keyframing preferences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/editing.html#keyframing), where you can make this the default behaviour.

> When an object is using constraints, the object property value does not actually change. Visual Keying will add keyframes to the object property, with a value based on the visual transformation from the constraint.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but how to properly use this? If I have for example a hand with child of constraint connected to cube, and want to save the absolute position and rotation, to make animation work properly even without constraint, do I have to use visual locRot? Because it doesn't work in that way, or I am doing something wrong, my hand goes in weird position and have weird rotation after applying visual locRot keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my add-on [Disable Constraint Without Moving](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sybrenstuvel/random-blender-addons/master/disable_constraint_without_moving.py) to, well, disable the constraint while keeping the object at its location/orientation.