# Move object parent without children

Tags: parent

Can I move the parent object without the children?
In all 3D software there is an option to turn on/off to move only the parent without the children. It is a fundamental function that is often used.

I've seen an answer in 2015, I would like to know if there are new ones and if anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what you've been trying but my way of getting around this problem is one of substitution.  Switch the child(ren) over to duplicates at the right frame and use those.  The duplicates are unparented and cleared of animation so they're completely independent of the parent.   You can also switch back to the original children at any time.  For details see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87906/robot-arm-move-a-box/87929#87929  My answer is at the bottom.

Comment: Try this addon, do exactly what is needed
http://www.kurzemnieks.com/center-object-to-children-blender-addon/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/nearby-objects-wont-move-independently

Answer (score 15):

Since Blender 2.81 the transformation can be limited to affect only the parents. The setting can be found in the header of the 3D View inside the drop down labelled *Options*. Once activated you can move, rotate and scale the parent object without affecting its children.

[image: Affect only parents]

Comment: If I enable this option and then change the position of the parent, the children are still moving with the parent..

Comment: That checkbox affects scaling tools but not typed-in transform values.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- A Parent. The Blender User can Make a Parent and Clear a Parent.  Shown in the search menu.
- Child of Constraint. Shown above not completed.  The [influence] can be keyframed for animation.  Therefore you can switch Control ... say from Left Hand to Right Hand as an example.

[image]

It behaves in a similar fashion to parent.  You can move the [child] or the target parent. By having a total of two constraints, one for each hand, you could move the yellow cylinder from hand to hand.  Set keyframes to control start and 
finish of control.

- Lastly there are Copy Location, Copy Rotation, and Copy Scale Constraints and other similar constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I'm looking for is a simple way to reposition the parent without moving the children.
It would be useful an addon!

Comment: There is one already - http://www.kurzemnieks.com/center-object-to-children-blender-addon/

Answer (score 2):

You can go into edit mode of the parent, move all vertices, go back to object mode and if desired use origin-modification like Object > Transform > Origin To Center Of Mass