# Is it possible to unparent an object on a specific keyframe?

Tags: animation, parent

I have tried to make an animation to test my skills so far (have only used blender in about 3 months). But I got a problem when the "robot arm" should take the letter and put it on the wall and then the arm would disappear from the camera(it will be a lot easier to understand if you look at the  [.blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArOXSnk_tgfngbsX_0UViOXhTy5zfA) ;). I am using parenting to make the animation easier to make but when the letter is on the wall I want it to stick there and not follow the arm but I don't know how to do it. Is it any way you can unparent an object on a specific keyframe? Or is it any other solution? Would appreciate an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm on mobile so I can't check your file. Did you try to :

1. Select your object (child)
2. In Properties go to *Object constraints*
3. On the last frame of constraint: Right clic on *Influence* and *insert keyframe* and change it to **1**
4. On the next frame: change it to **0**
5. You might click on *set inverse* if the object move

Comment: You might also like to cast an eye over this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87906/robot-arm-move-a-box/87929#87929